# Akeneo 2.1.4 : How can I remove a product from a product model?

Tags: product, akeneo, pim

In Akeneo, I can assign default products to product models, but there does not seem to be an obvious way to unassign them back to default products. I've tried importing a new feed, but it shows me the error message that I am not allowed to change the variant axis.

Does anyone know how I can remove a product from a product model?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as I speak (*Akeneo PIM v2.1*) **it's not possible** to detach a variant product from its parent to make it a "simple" product.

To achieve this, you could try some custom code, but **I did not tested it and can't guarantee you that it would works**. You would have to change the behavior of the `ParentFieldSetter` (https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/2.1/src/Pim/Component/Catalog/Updater/Setter/ParentFieldSetter.php#L38) to allow it to set null parent value.

Prior to this, you would have to be sure your `Product` object contains values from parent above.